# JAVA: verify user input for one character

Tags: java, input

this is my first time asking a question. If I'm breaking any rules let me know please :)

I want to verify that the user only types in only one character and store in a variable I have already declared initially. As well, loop back the question for user to type in again if they did not do what they are asked for

Here is a what I have done so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class arraytesting {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user_Choice;
    int rowAndcolumns;
    char[][] user_Array;
    char user_Char;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1 to 9): ");
        user_Choice = myKeyboard.nextInt();
        if (user_Choice < 1 || user_Choice > 9)
            System.out.println("Illegal choice, please try again.");
    } while (user_Choice < 1 || user_Choice > 9);

    switch (user_Choice) {
    case 1:
        do {
            System.out.print("\nHow many rows and columns (min 4 & max 20)? ");
            rowAndcolumns = myKeyboard.nextInt();
            if (rowAndcolumns < 1 || rowAndcolumns > 9)
                System.out.println("Illegal choice, please try again.");
        } while (rowAndcolumns < 4 || rowAndcolumns > 20);

        do {
            System.out.print("Which character do you want to fill your square with? (only one character)");
            user_Char = myKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if () // error message for user if they did not type correctly, Idk what to put in the
            System.out.println("Illegal choice, please try again.");// boolean for it to compare
                System.out.print(user_Char);
        } while (); // using do-while loop to loop back question, if they don't type in correctly, i
                                // would only like for user to type in only one character
        break;
    }
}
```

}

I know I can put both of them in one do-while loop, but I want to focus on getting the boolean to check for user input.

edit: I would only like the user to enter only one single character 
ex. '@' or 'a' 
whereas "@@" or "i am typing something that is not one character" is wrong 
inside the spaces of `if` and `while` are how I want it to be verified

Comment: Could you please update your code to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? `user_Char` isn't declared anywhere. Also your indentations are a bit wacky, which makes it hard to properly read the code.

Comment: Regarding your second question, leaving `rowAndcolumns` uninitialized should be perfectly fine. What error message do you get when you don't initialize `rowAndcolumns`?

Comment: By default, int in Java is implicitly initialized to 0

Comment: Sorry about that, I editted my post. Let me know if I can improve the formatting further.

Comment: Are you trying to convert `user_Char` which is a char to boolean?

Comment: @LeBronJames Only if it's a class member, which is not the case here. But it gets initialized before it's being used, so that shouldn't be a problem. Of course if it's used after the `case 1` block it'll give an error because it might not be initialized, but no such usage is visible in OPs example code.

Comment: I'm trying to compare `user_Char` to something if user does not type in the correct input

Comment: @ClubSavage Right now your code doesn't compile, because you can't use a char as a boolean statement. I am not sure what exactly you are asking or trying to do. "Compare to something" isn't very specific. Please update your question to describe **precisely** what you actually want to do, and why it's not working.

Comment: _"if user does not type in the correct input"_ It would already be helpful to know, what input is considered correct or incorrect.

Comment: @MaxVollmer sorry, I'm still learning the ropes here, I edited my post again. I would like the user to only enter one character and verify if they did or not. ex. '@' or 'a' whereas "@@" or "i am typing something that is not one character" is wrong inside the spaces of if and while are how I want it to be verified

Comment: @ClubSavage How is that supposed to work? It's your code that decides how many characters it reads from input. If a user enters 2 characters, what they actually did was enter 1 character and then after that enter 1 character again. When you receive the first character you can't predict the future and see if another character will come or not. To check if more characters are entered, you must wait for them, essentially breaking the program for any user who does the right thing and only enters 1 character. Just take 1 character from `myKeyboard`, handle it, and don't worry about further input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do any check for "only 1 character entered". That makes no sense. You can't predict the future, so you cannot know if a user will enter more characters after 1 character has been entered. You will either just take the first character entered and work with it and ignore any potential additional characters - or you have to wait for more than 1 character, essentially breaking the program for users who do the right thing (enter only one character), just to be able to give them an error message when they finally do the wrong thing (enter another character).

That being said, this code:

```
user_Char = myKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
```

will actually wait for several characters to be entered until some kind of delimiter (per default some whitespace character, e.g. newline) is entered. That's exactly *what you do not want*.

You want to get one character from input, and one only. You don't have to care about more characters being entered after that:

```
user_Char = myKeyboard.next(".").charAt(0);
```

This tells `myKeyboard` to return the next `String` that matches the regex *"."*, which is any character, and only 1 character.

If you want to validate the entered character, e.g. only alphanumeric characters allowed, you can update your `if` and `while` to something like this:

```
if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]", new String(user_Char)))
```

or even better, use the `String` returned by `myKeyboard.next(".")`:

```
String user_String = myKeyboard.next(".");
user_Char = user_String.charAt(0);
if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]", user_String))
```

or you could directly tell `myKeyboard` to only allow valid characters and skip the entire `do/if/while` error handling:

```
user_Char = myKeyboard.next("[a-zA-Z0-9]").charAt(0);
```

**Edit**

One thing your code doesn't handle right now is invalid inputs, e.g. letters when you call `nextInt`. This will actually throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`, and you might want to wrap your `nextInt()` and `next(...)` calls in `try-catch` blocks to handle these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below, based on the discussion with Max, I used the `.length()` method to check the lenght of the string that the user typed.

You can check the type of the character to avoid the `runtime` exception   in the first if statement using some methods in Character class that you use to check if the input is digit/letter or not ?

> Character.isDigit(char)
>
> Character.isLetter(char)
>
> Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)

I also changed some variable names, Java is following the `camel case` style and class name has to be capitalized. I also refactored some code to check the range of the numbers to git rid of repeating same code on and on, check the method `betweenExclusive`

```
package stackoverflow.q2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice;
    int rowAndcolumns;
    char[][] user_Array;
    char userChar;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1 to 9): ");
        userChoice = myKeyboard.nextInt();
        if ( !betweenExclusive(userChoice, 1,9) )
            System.out.println("Illegal choice, please try again.");
    } while (!betweenExclusive(userChoice, 1,9));

    switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            do {
                System.out.print("\nHow many rows and columns (min 4 & max 20)? ");
                rowAndcolumns = myKeyboard.nextInt();
                if (!betweenExclusive(rowAndcolumns ,1 , 9))
                    System.out.println("Illegal choice, please try again.");
            } while (!betweenExclusive(rowAndcolumns ,4 , 20));

            String input;
            while (true){
                System.out.print("Which character do you want to fill your square with? (only one character)");
                input = myKeyboard.next();
                // error message for user if they did not type correctly, Idk what to put in the
                // boolean for it to compare
                if ( input.length()>1){
                    System.out.print("Illegal character, try again please !!! ");
                }else{
                    userChar = input.charAt(0);
                    System.out.print(userChar);
                    break;
                }
            }  // using do-while loop to loop back question, if they don't type in correctly, i
            // would only like for user to type in only one character
        break;
    }
}

public static boolean betweenExclusive(int x, int min, int max)
{
    return x>=min && x<=max;
}
```

}

Comment: _"Let me know if that answers your question please ..."_ Better to ask for clarifications in the comments first, before posting speculations as answer.

Comment: I answered based on the conversation down beneath the question, check the conversation history before downgrading other's answers

Comment: I am part of that conversation, there is nothing about digits there.

Comment: isDigit() was an example of what he can check for, there are other functions available in the Character class he can use like isLetter() ... etc ... you love your answer , that is fine but don't be prejudice

Comment: Downvoting helps improve answers and questions. This is not "prejudice", and it has nothing to do with my answer, this is merely a tool for maintaining high quality. Please don't mistake constructive criticism and downvoting with personal attacks or ill intent. The question was _how to check that only one character was entered_, not _what character was entered_. Therefore your answer isn't relevant to the question OP has asked. You have a chance to improve your answer, and I am more than willing to upvote once you have done that.

Comment: I see what happen now, I misunderstood the requirements but I am going to update my answer to match what he needs. I am sorry about what I said in the other comment.

Comment: The relevant bit in my answer is `user_Char = myKeyboard.next(".").charAt(0);`, the rest is just sugar. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Another option would be to use `next()` and then check the resulting String length. I haven't posted that, but maybe you could? I'd upvote.

Comment: I updated the answer based on our conversation and did some code refactoring as well. Thanks :)